# Scrapy can't crawl all pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape one ecommerce page with scrapy and the code looks like this

```
class HugobossSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hugoboss'
    allowed_domains = ['hugoboss.com/de/herren-schuhe/?sz=60&start=0']
    start_urls = ['https://hugoboss.com/de/herren-schuhe/?sz=60&start=0']

    def parse(self, response):
    # The main method of the spider. It scrapes the URL(s) specified in the
    # 'start_url' argument above. The content of the scraped URL is passed on
    # as the 'response' object.

        nextpageurl = response.xpath("//a[@title='Weiter']/@href")

        for item in self.scrape(response):
            yield item

        if nextpageurl:
            path = nextpageurl.extract_first()
            nextpage = response.urljoin(path)
            print("Found url: {}".format(nextpage))
            yield Request(nextpage, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
    #Extracting the content using css selectors
        url = response.xpath('//div/@data-mouseoverimage').extract()
        product_title = response.xpath('//*[@class="product-      tile__productInfoWrapper product-tile__productInfoWrapper--is-small font__subline"]/text()').extract()
        price = response.css('.product-tile__offer .price-sales::text').getall()
    #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(url,product_title,price):
        #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            item = {
              'URL' : item[0],
              'Product Name' : item[1].replace("\n", '').replace("von", ""),
              'Price' : item[2]
            }

        #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield item
```

The problem is the code is extracting the information of the current page but cannot extract information for all the pages.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined twice the function `def parse()`
Rename the second one (maybe `def extract()`) and try again.